# Teen sci-fi book - Stonehenge type structure reference

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to remember a book I read several times as a kid, so sometime in the 90s. It involved a structure that was basically Stonehenge (was something very important regarding signage that said to "stay on the path"), 3 generations of characters (1 male - Celtic maybe? 1 female - current time and another male that was from the future (alien?))

The Stonehenge structure and 3 different timelines are all I can really remember. IIRC all 3 characters wound up together at the end to save the day.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction and Fantasy SE, take a look at [this checklist](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to see if you can think of any other details, like when you read it? Etc.

Comment: If there was a dragon also, it might have been *Her Majesty's Wizard* by Christopher Stasheff. The humans in the alternate-Stonehenge ring were knight Sir Guy Losobal, Her Majesty Alisande of Merovence, and Matthew from Earth. No signage, though.

Comment: In the Circle of Time by Margaret Anderson?